# Building a project off Laravel -- should I fork?

Tags: php, git, laravel, github, frameworks

I'm building a public project with a framework. I think I'm going to go with Laravel, which exists on Github.

My question's super simple:
**Should I fork Laravel as the base of my project?**

I'm not familiar with Github ettiquite and I'm wondering if forking is the best way to make sure my framework codebase is up-to-date.

Comment: The answer depends on if you want to just *use* the framework, or make changes to the core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do fork the Laravel repo. You can add it as a git submodule to your repo. Though it would be easier to use composer in order to add the Laravel dependency (http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/).

Comment: Does using Composer automatically add this submodule information so that git commits will include it?

Comment: Nope, but do you need this info?

Comment: It'll be an open-source community project, so the easier it is for people to get set up the better place we'll be in.

Comment: Well, that's the goal of composer, to allow developers to specify dependencies for their project so that newcomers can install all dependencies will only one command.